Computing the CECDF (Complementary Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function) in R
The ECDF can be calculated using the function ecdf() in R.
I have the following expression I'd like to define in terms of the CECDF, but for some odd reason things are not matching up.
The expression is
\begin{align}
p &= \frac{\#\{d \geq a\}}{\#\{d\}} \\[1mm]
\end{align}
which should equal $1 - F_d(a)$, where $F$ denotes the CDF.
In R, $p$ is just
p <- mean(d >= a).

Using ecdf(), this is
ecdf_d <- ecdf(a)
p_cecdf <- 1 - ecdf_d

Here is a full MRE to illustrate the issue:
set.seed(123)

d <- rnorm(100)
f <- rnorm(50)
a <- min(f)
b <- min(a)
d_ecdf <- ecdf(d)
f_ecdf <- ecdf(f)
(p_cecdf <- 1 - d_ecdf(b))
# [1] 0.99
(q_cecdf <- 1 - f_ecdf(a))
# [1] 0.98
res_d <- mean(d >= b)
# [1] 0.99
res_f <- mean(f >= a)
# [1] 1

Unless I'm forgetting something, shouldn't $p_\mathrm{cecdf} = res\_d$ and $q_\mathrm{cecdf} = res\_f$

The assumption "$p = \frac{\#\{d \geq a\}}{\#\{d\}}$ which should equal $1-F_d(a)$" is not correct.
The CDF is defined as $F_d(a) = \text{Pr}(D \le a)$. When you are dealing with a discrete set of points, that's equivalent to $\frac{\#\{d \leq a\}}{\#\{d\}}$. The complement of that, $1-F_d(a)$, is not $\text{Pr}(D \ge a)$, but $\text{Pr}(D \gt a)=\frac{\#\{d \gt a\}}{\#\{d\}}$.
R example:
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
CDF <- ecdf(x)
a <- 1
CDF(a) # = Pr(x <= a)
1-CDF(a) # this Pr(x > a)
mean(x > a) # correctly calculating the CECDF
mean(x >= a) # but this is actually what you want to calculate


Ah, yes. This is exactly what I had suspected since the ECDF is a discrete function.

If you want $\geq$ nevertheless just take the complement of the ecdf and add the proportion at the equality

@Glen_b Thanks. I'll consider that.
